# WebClient Spring Filters order of call

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have Spring WebClient reactive, I defined filter that adds a header ("Authorization", with some value lets say value is "JWT1...."), for the following request.

After I build `webclient` and attached `filter.(do it in the bean)`
wired from bean config

```
WebClient webClient;

webClient.get().uir(someuri).header("x-app-name","appname").header("Authorization","jwttoken2")
.retrieve().bodyToMono(Someclass);
```

When I make such call, what happens first header `"Authorization"` set to `"jwttoken2"` and after filter is invokes, and overriding value with `"JWT1.."`, or filter is called first and sets the `Authorization` header to `JWT1` and then `.header` function is called and overriding the value to `Jwttoken2`.

So what is the order of calls ?

Answer (score 0):

Value from Filter will be applied last overriding the value in .header("name","value")